# How do I use Linq to select the top/bottom N contestants in a Ranked Choice Vote?

Tags: c#, linq, task-parallel-library, system.reactive, plinq

I am trying to use Linq (and eventually parallel Linq) calculate the top N ballots in a [Ranked Choice Vote / Alternative Vote](http://www.cgpgrey.com/politics-in-the-animal-kingdom/)

I'm using the following code to generate several ballots with a structured output.

My question is, how can I use Linq to tell me any of:

- The `Count()` of votes for a given Contestant
- The actual ballots for a given contestant, where `count() = n`
- The actual contestants that received no votes

I'm just struggling with the initial query, and can hack the rest once I have a starting point.

If I have time, I'll have fun with this and send the ballots to Task Parallel Library / RX where I can compute the results in real time.

[image]

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace RankedChoiceDataGenerator
{

    public static class ThreadSafeRandom
    {
        [ThreadStatic] private static Random Local;

        public static Random ThisThreadsRandom
        {
            get { return Local ?? (Local = new Random(unchecked(Environment.TickCount * 31 + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))); }
        }
    }
    static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)
        {
            int n = list.Count;
            while (n > 1)
            {
                n--;
                int k = ThreadSafeRandom.ThisThreadsRandom.Next(n + 1);
                T value = list[k];
                list[k] = list[n];
                list[n] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class BallotEntry
    {
        public int ContestantID { get; set; }
        public int OrderedPreferenceForContestant { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Contestant " +ContestantID + " was assigned to " + OrderedPreferenceForContestant + " place";
        }
    }

    // will be much more efficent as a struct
    public class Ballot
    {
        public BallotEntry[] Entries { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "This ballot voted for " + Entries.Length + " positions";
        }
    }

    class MainClass
    {

        public static List<Ballot> BallotsToTally = new List<Ballot>();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var numberOfBallots = 5;
            var thingsToVoteOn = 10;

            Random r = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBallots ; i++)
            { 
                // One Ballot per voter
                Ballot b = new Ballot();

                // Voters can vote for as many or as few as they want
                int numOfEntries = r.Next(1, thingsToVoteOn );
                b.Entries = new BallotEntry[numOfEntries];

                // Ranked Vote simulation
                var randomSetOfThings = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, thingsToVoteOn));
                randomSetOfThings.Shuffle();

                var preferenceOrder = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, numOfEntries ));
                preferenceOrder.Shuffle();
                for (int n = 0; n < numOfEntries ; n++)
                {
                    b.Entries[n] = new BallotEntry();

                    // Choose a random thing
                    b.Entries[n].ContestantID = randomSetOfThings[n];

                    // Vote on the random thing using ranked vote
                    b.Entries[n].OrderedPreferenceForContestant = preferenceOrder[n ];
                }

                BallotsToTally.Add(b);
            }

            // Process ballots
            // Create Snapshot of Phase 1
            // find the bottom and top ranking items in the list



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "The actual ballots for a given contestant, where `count() = n`" mean?

Answer (score 1):

This gives you an answer to questions (1) & (3):

```
    var votesPerContestant =
        BallotsToTally
            .SelectMany(x => x.Entries.Select(y => y.ContestantID))
            .GroupBy(x => x)
            .Select(x => new { ContestantID = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.ContestantID, x => x.Count);

    var votesForContestant2 = votesPerContestant[2];

    var contestantsWithNoVotes =
        Enumerable
            .Range(1, thingsToVoteOn)
            .Where(x => !votesPerContestant.ContainsKey(x))
            .ToArray();
```

I don't know what you mean by "The actual ballots for a given contestant, where `count() = n`" so I couldn't answer that one.

Now, since you're trying to produce a voting system it is unlikely that Parallel LINQ will help as you have to compare all candidates to each other AND you have a relatively small set of values to work with. Parallel LINQ works best when you are performing independent computations on a large set of values.

Also, I assume that you want to use either TPL or Rx to simulate one ballot arriving at a time and having the system produce stats on which candidate is currently winning? That's a perfect scenario for Rx, but you'd need more detail on how to compute a winner for me to give you any suggestions on that.

---

And here's the code for determining a winner using the Alternative Vote method:

```
    var ballots = BallotsToTally.Select(x => x.Entries.OrderBy(y => y.OrderedPreferenceForContestant).Select(y => y.ContestantID).ToArray()).ToArray();
    var active = Enumerable.Range(1, thingsToVoteOn).ToList();
    var top = (IGrouping<int, int>)null;

    while (active.Count() > 0)
    {
        var votes =
            from a in active
            join v in ballots.Select(x => x.Where(y => active.Contains(y)).FirstOrDefault()).Where(x => x != 0) on a equals v into gvs
            select new { candidate = a, votes = gvs.Count() };

        var ranks =
            votes
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.votes)
                .ThenBy(x => x.candidate)
                .GroupBy(x => x.votes, x => x.candidate)
                .ToArray();

        top = ranks.First();

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, ranks.Select(x => $"{x.Key} votes for {String.Join(", ", x)}")));
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (var candidate in ranks.Last())
        {
            active.Remove(candidate);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Winner(s) {top.Key} votes for {String.Join(", ", top)}");
```

If we start with:

```
    var numberOfBallots = 500;
    var thingsToVoteOn = 10;
```

... then this is a sample run:

```
64 votes for 5
54 votes for 2
51 votes for 1
50 votes for 7
49 votes for 4
48 votes for 8
47 votes for 6, 10
46 votes for 3
44 votes for 9

67 votes for 5
59 votes for 2
56 votes for 7
55 votes for 10
54 votes for 1
53 votes for 3
52 votes for 4, 6
49 votes for 8

69 votes for 5
66 votes for 7
64 votes for 2
62 votes for 10
58 votes for 4, 6
57 votes for 1
54 votes for 3

77 votes for 5
75 votes for 7
72 votes for 2
68 votes for 10
66 votes for 4
64 votes for 1
60 votes for 6

85 votes for 5
82 votes for 2
81 votes for 4
80 votes for 7
75 votes for 10
70 votes for 1

96 votes for 5
94 votes for 2
93 votes for 4
92 votes for 7
79 votes for 10

114 votes for 4
113 votes for 2
111 votes for 5
104 votes for 7

142 votes for 4
137 votes for 2, 5

261 votes for 4

Winner(s) 261 votes for 4
```

Comment: In the Ranked Choice Vote, there is a need to edit a ballot once a candidate has been eliminated (e.g. The potato party has been eliminated, therefore the new 'first choice' will be a bit more mainstream, causing the old second place to become the first place.  This is where `count()=n` comes in.  See the linked youtube videos, quite entertaining )

Comment: @TLDR - I watched the Alternative Vote but still don't see where `count() = n` comes in, but I understand the voting mechanism. It should be fairly easy to implement.

Comment: Perhaps my perceived approach is too complex, or redundant in some way I can't see

Comment: @TLDR - I've added the code for working out a winner.